# How get list data from specific node firebase realtime db in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: I want get this destination list data]

This is my sample code for other data

```
 DatabaseReference rideRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('rideRequest/$rideID');
rideRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  Navigator.pop(context);
  if(snapshot.value != null){

    print(snapshot.value);
    double pickupLat = double.parse(snapshot.value['pickup_location']['latitude'].toString());
    double pickupLng = double.parse(snapshot.value['pickup_location']['longitude'].toString());
    String pickupAddress = snapshot.value['pickup_address'].toString();
```

How do to get that destination list data.Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question like that.

```
List<DestLocation> destLocation = [];
List<dynamic> result;

result = snapshot.value['destination'];
    result.forEach((value) {
        if (value != null) {
          DestLocation _a = DestLocation(
              placeName: value["destination_address"].toString(),
              latitude: double.parse(value["latitude"]),
              longitude: double.parse(value["longitude"])
          );
          destLocation.add(_a);
        }
      });
```